# Spring Boot application runs but don't open in navigator by server

Tags: spring-boot, apache, deployment

I have a Spring Boot aplication hosted in a server that runs normally in a linux machine. I am using aaPanel with the apache server. My aplication is running in the port 8080, but I can't access it by the URL of the server. I get the error page "The requested URL was not found on this server." What may be the problem?

I've tried to change the port 80 in apache configuration file but it doesn't work. My aplication runs normally when I run locally by the IDE IntelliJ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.